# Track number of widget views remotely

Tags: javascript, widget, analytics, web-analytics

Here is the scenario I am trying to create:

I want to put a widget on one domain (`http://www.example.com`), and track the number of times that widget is loaded/rendered, in order to accurately measure the number of visitors to that domain. This needs to then be sent across to another domain (`http://www.example2.com/API`) which recieves the signal, and increments the count of visitors by one (In the database).

I have tried to do some research on this, but I haven't been able to find a clear answer/solution to this problem (I did find one question what was very similar, but I was unable to understand the answer given : [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481659/track-number-of-impressions-of-a-widget-running-on-a-remote-website)

I am new to widget programming, and am trying to learn if this process is possible, and if so, how I can go about implementing it. So please point me in the right direction! I apologise if any of this is unclear.

Comment: How do you plan to "put a widget" on the target website? Will it be a Javascript embed for example?

Comment: It will be a javascript embed, yes! Unless there is a better way to do so that I am unaware of :)

Comment: But as stated I am extremely new to widget programming, so I am still learning about how widgets work. As a working example, lets say I want to put this widget onto a wordpress blog, by using their custom code widget to enter my code. Ideally this will be used by users of my site, in order to help me track their visitor counts for internal purposes.

Answer (score 0):

When developing JavaScript embedded widgets, the most common way of tracking visitors is letting the JavaScript insert an image tag with a specially crafted URL. At the server one simply counts how many times the URL is requested. Using cookies it is also possible to count unique visitors.

This URL usually simply responds with a 1x1 pixel transparent GIF image.